# Using 無理 to empathise

Tags: set-phrases

`無理` seems to be a part of some standard phrases whenever I would wish to empathise with a person who in unwell or in distress.
Could someone help with examples of such phrases, and the context where it is appropriate to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the phrase you're referring to is 無理しないでください and its variants. For example, you'd say this when you make a request of someone and realize that it might be a large undertaking or inconvenience, and you want to express that the person you are asking doesn't need to go to such troubles for your sake. More generally, you would use this phrase when you express hope that someone should not overexert themselves, like when they are sick or under some sort of physical or mental distress.

Comment: Are there any other such phrases using 無理?

Comment: @IUnknown there aren't any other fixed expressions that I can think of at the moment, but it's certainly possible to empathize with someone and kind of agree that something is 無理, like if your friend's boss asked them to do a week's worth of work in 3 days you could call that 無理 as a form of empathy.